# Specify location with Task Scheduler script

Tags: powershell, scheduled-tasks

I'm trying to write a PowerShell script that will activate another script on a daily basis. What I have is:

```
$Sta = New-ScheduledTaskAction -Execute "powershell.exe" -argument "C:\Users\UserName\Desktop\Script.ps1"
$Stt = New-ScheduledTaskTrigger -Daily -At 3am
Register-ScheduledTask Task1 -Action $Sta -Trigger $Stt
```

It's not working because it can't find the file. PowerShell's default directory is the user's root directory, so I don't know if that's it, even though I've tried using the full path to the file? Or is it due to where the scheduled task is running from? Location says \ and I cannot seem to change that, even in the task scheduler app. I've been Googling for days and I can't figure it out. Anyone have any idea? I'm working on Windows 10 Pro.

Comment: It seems like you are running the task as a user that has no access to the `C:\Users\UserName\Desktop` path. Probably because this is a service account that does not have a desktop path. Better store the script file straight onto the C:\ drive or create a dedicated subfolder for your scheduled task scripts and make sure the user running the task has read/execute rights on that folder. I would also change the argument string into `"-File 'C:\ScriptFolder\Script.ps1'"`

Comment: That's not it as I'm running it as the administrator, and it's on the admin's desktop. I tried what you suggested though, and there's no change.

Answer (score 0):

Soufflegirl13,

Updated & Tested:

```
$TaskSet = New-ScheduledTaskSettingsSet -Compatibility Win8
$TaskSet.DisallowStartIfOnBatteries = $True
$TaskSet.StopIfGoingOnBatteries     = $True
$TaskSet.IdleSettings.StopOnIdleEnd = $false
#Adjust the following two lines to meet your requirements
$TaskDesc = "Retrieve the status of HyperV" 
$TaskName = "Task1 - or whatever you want here"

$Stt = New-ScheduledTaskTrigger -Daily -At 3am

#Adjust the -file parameter to point to your script
$TAArgs = @{Execute  = '"' + "c:\windows\system32\windowspowershell" +
                             "\v1.0\powershell.exe" + '"' ;
            Argument = "-file `"G:\BEKDocs\Scripts\Misc\Get-HyperVStatus-V-3.ps1`""                  }
                             
$TaskAction = New-ScheduledTaskAction @TAArgs

$RSTArgs = @{Action      = $TaskAction
             TaskName    = "$TaskName"
             Trigger     = $Stt
             User        = "$env:USERDOMAIN\$env:username"
             RunLevel    = "Highest"
             Description = "$TaskDesc"
             Settings    = $TaskSet}

Register-ScheduledTask @RSTargs
```

I've found that forcing the quote marks around the powershell filespec solved some problems. You might want to try it around the script name if the previous doesn't work.

Of course adjust any settings as you see fit to meet your requirements. Also I've not used this basic code to set a trigger before but I adjusted it to do so according to the documentation for Register-ScheduledTask so it should work.

Update Notes:

I checked the documentation for the New-ScheduledTaskSettingsSet cmdlet and it doesn't include Win10 as a valid value for Compatibility, go figure, so I backed it off to Win8. You can also just not use the Compatibility argument and accept whatever it defaults to.

The code is now fully tested, sorry I forgot to tell you to replace the $TaskName variable with a value or to add the variable, as is now shown in the adjusted code.

HTH

Comment: That's giving me a ParserError on line 9, and I can't figure out why...

Comment: @soufflegirl13 Change the comma into a semi-colon `;` in line 9: `"\v1.0\powershell.exe" + '"'  ;`

Comment: Thanks! I tried that, but now it gives me a bunch of errors. "The property 'DisallowStartIfOnBatteries'  'StopIfGoingOnBatteries'   'StopOnIdleEnd' cannot be found on this object. Verify that the property exists and can be set." and "REgister-ScheduledTask @RSTargs Cannot validate argument on parameter 'Settings'. The argument is null or empty. Provide an argument that is not null or empty, and then try the command again."

Comment: soufflegirl13, then just delete those lines from the top of the script.

Comment: @RetiredGeek I tried that, but unfortunately it then complains about Description, and then Settings and then TaskName and then finally just says access is denied after removing those. I seriously think something is wrong with the module on my system or something.

Comment: @soufflegirl13, script has been adjusted and notes added. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Thanks @RetiredGeek! The Hypervisor lines were just an example, correct? I'll change then out for what mine is? I had to take the RunLevel line out (that was what was causing the access denied error, which I'm confused about as I'm the admin) and the script runs now. When it activates it just shows some error text and then closes again though. I've been trying to catch it with the snipping tool to read it, but no luck yet. The script it's activating does run properly, so that isn't it. Any idea what else might be causing it?

Comment: @soufflegirl13, change your question to add your current script so we can see what you're actually using.

Comment: @RetiredGeek It's ok, I'm just going to put this aside. I've wasted too much time on it, and it's totally not worth it at this point. I've got exams, and I'm pretty sure it's just some setting in my computer that's causing the problem. I really appreciate all the help you all have given me though! I've learned a lot regardless! Sorry this was so annoying!